# jQuery.post uses modified url of current location instead of supplied one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with my jquery.post call.

When I execute following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //var cmsr_url = 'http://127.0.0.1/sphere/modules/cmsrating/ajax.php?rand=1231';
        var cmsr_url = 'ajax/test.html';

        $('.star, .auto-submit-star').rating({
            callback: function(value, link){
                alert(cmsr_url);
                $.post({
                    url: cmsr_url,
                    // also tried to put here a string like below
                    // url: 'http://127.0.0.1/sphere/modules/cmsrating/ajax.php?rand=1231'
                    data: {rating : value},
                    success: function(){
                        alert('done!');
                    },
                    dataType: 'json'
                });
            } 

        });

    });
</script>
```

My alert shows corrent url. However my firebug shows that requested url is:

`http://127.0.0.1/sphere/pl/content/%5Bobject%20Object%5D`

Where does it get from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are trying to use $.post function as if you are using $.ajax function. From documentation it looks like post does not accept options like $.ajax does. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

try this instead:

```
$.ajax({
    url: cmsr_url,
    // also tried to put here a string like below
    // url: 'http://127.0.0.1/sphere/modules/cmsrating/ajax.php?rand=1231'
    data: {rating : value},
    success: function(){
     alert('done!');
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST'
});
```

Comment: This one works. But what is wrong with post... it should be shorthand to $.ajax

Comment: see my edited answer for the reason, @MyP3uK has the correct solution here

Comment: yes it is the shorthand for $.ajax but accepts list of parameters not one "option" obejct

Comment: if you wanted to still use `$.post` just take out the `url:` property and make that the first param like `$.post(cmsr_url, {/*options*/})`

Comment: Right! I paste $.ajax syntax and changed it to post later. But didnt notice difference in object vs parameters. So obvious. So stupid!

Comment: Edited to show better what was the problem. Thank you all for help!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
url: cmsr_url.toString(),
```

in your case the `http://127.0.0.1/sphere/pl/content/%5Bobject%20Object%5D`
means that cmsr_url is object, not a string, and probably it can be typecasted to string

Comment: He assigns it with a string literal, how could it be an object?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are passing an `Object` where a `String` is expected. The end of your url is a url-encoded version of `[object Object]` which is what is returned when `toString()` is called on a plain object.

<del>Check that the value of `value` being passed in to your callback is a string rather than an object.


--EDIT--

Are you constructing `cmsr_url` by concatenating strings? Make sure all the parts are really strings, and not plain objects.</del>

--EDIT--

as @MyP3uK pointed out in his correct answer, this is because you are passing an options object to `$.post`, where only a string url is expected.

Comment: How would the `value` argument get into the URL?

Comment: via the `.data` property. It should be converted to a query string should it not?

Comment: Actually, wait, you're right that doesn't make sense

Comment: That would be right if it were `$.get`, but not `$.post`.

Comment: MyP3uK has the correct answer. Why are you grasping at random straws?

Comment: random straws? I put up an answer and you noticed there was a problem with it, so I corrected it. @MyP3uK has a different answer, so let the OP see if that solves his problem, and check it off if it does. If it doesn't maybe my answer will help him out, maybe not. This is the purpose of having multiple answers.

Comment: isn't it clear that his answer is correct? You can see in his question how he's contructing `cmsr_url`, it's a string literal.

Comment: @Barmar btw I hadn't even seen that answer while filling out my own. I can see now that it is correct, gave it an upvote. I don't see why there's anything wrong with trying to fix the answer I gave.

Comment: Resolved. Best answer is right one. I passed parameter object as 1st parameter isntead of splitting it into many aparameters.
That made 1st parameter to be an object.